# How can I set the default ios simulator that my Xamarin.UITest Suite uses?

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, xamarin.uitest

My Xamarin.UITests keeps defaulting to use iPhone SE. I would like it to default it to use iPhone 12 Pro. I am able to specify the device I want to use by adding `.DeviceIdentifier(#UUID#)` but I would like it to do so by default.

My expectation is that when I change the device in my list of devices when running in debug mode, it will also change the default device being used by the UITests. But this has not been the case, any thoughts on how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

My understanding of how VS for mac chooses a simulated device is based on what it perceives as the newest device you have access to per Apple OS. This is of course outside of you using .DeviceIdentifier(#UUID#) which I would always suggest. Now if you really want to make a default you could kind of trick your system. You would do this by deleting all your simulators out of your simulator folder and only installing just the ones you want to have or just the one you want as a default. That would guarantee that VS for mac would just choose the one you want